# Android Development Tools( ADT) stops working when creating new projects

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I installed the latest ADT in my machine. But when trying to create a new project in it, it waits for sometime and then stops working showing the following error message:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-jar /home/deathholes/ide/eclipse-adt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/deathholes/ide/eclipse-adt/eclipse/eclipse-adt
-name Eclipse-adt
--launcher.library /home/deathholes/ide/eclipse-adt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/deathholes/ide/eclipse-adt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 68a804e
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-jar /home/deathholes/ide/eclipse-adt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

in the terminal the following error message is shown:

```
Exception in thread "Worker-8" Exception in thread "Worker-6" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Worker-8"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Worker-6"
Error while logging event loop exception:
```

I tried to increase the heap and permspace by editing the eclipse.ini file and it nows looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=1572M
-Xms512M
-Xmx1572M
-Declipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759

java -version output:
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)</pre>
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit version. And the ADT is the latest one i.e, sdk22,64 bit

Comment: I seriously doubt that the problem is the heap size. The problem is probably a corrupted workspace. It might also be a corrupted installation, either Eclipse or ADT (or both), or a misbehaving plugin unrelated to ADT.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @TedHopp. Have you tried loading a different (new, clean) workspace when opening Eclipse?

Comment: I'm using a fresh install of ADT. and its not the plugin version. Its the total development kit.